# Can't login to heroku through firewall

Tags: firewall, ssl-certificate, login, heroku

I'm trying to connect to heroku via CLI (using heroku's Toolbelt) and I'm unable to do so. When I type my credentials, heroku replies with:

`Post https://api.heroku.com/login: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I'm inside a company's firewall that blocks most connections, and I have to use a certificate to navigate.

What can I do to login to heroku via cli?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue because of my organization's firewall. Solution is to simply [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940396/how-to-export-certificate-from-chrome-on-a-mac) and install the organization's certs.

1. Once you have your organization's specific ".cer" file then convert that file to ".pem" using

   ```
   openssl x509 -inform der -in orgCertFile.cer -out certificate.pem
   ```
2. Next, set following variable either as system variable or temp variable in current command line

   ```
   export SSL_CERT_FILE=orgCertFile.cer
   export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=certificate.pem
   ```
3. Finally try logging in using heroku command

   ```
   heroku login
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your proxy and then issue the heroku login command

Source : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy

> Using an HTTP proxy If you’re behind a firewall that requires use of a
>   proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services, you can set the
>   HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in your local
>   developer environment, before running the heroku command. For example,
>   on a Unix system you could do something like this:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber 
or 
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber 
$ heroku login
```

> On a
>   Windows machine, either set it in the System Properties/Environment
>   Variables, or do it from the terminal:

```
>  set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber 
or    
>  set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber    
>  heroku login
```